# Drupal 6, adding a admin menu?

Tags: 6, routes

I have a new module I made called kameleon_create_report, and I want to add a menu item to Reports. So I created my .module

```
<?php
function create_report() {
    print "test";
}

function kameleon_create_report_menu() {
    $items['admin/reports/orderreport'] = array(
        'title' => 'Order Report',
        'page callback' => 'create_report',
        'weight' => 1,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
      );
}
?>
```

And the info

```
; $Id$
name = Create Report
description = Report generator for orders
core = 6.x
```

But it's not showing up, even after a refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing one of either `access callback` or `access arguments`:

From the [`hook_menu()` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6):

> "access callback": A function returning TRUE if the user has access rights to this menu item, and FALSE if not. It can also be a boolean constant instead of a function, and you can also use numeric values (will be cast to boolean). Defaults to user_access() unless a value is inherited from the parent menu item; only MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK items can inherit access callbacks. To use the user_access() default callback, you must specify the permission to check as 'access arguments'

Sorry to paste so much but it's all relevant, the last sentence in particular.

Choose a permission that applies to your site and added it to your menu item:

```
function kameleon_create_report_menu() {
  $items['admin/reports/orderreport'] = array(
    'title' => 'Order Report',
    'page callback' => 'create_report',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), // This is almost certainly NOT the permission you want to use, choose one with restricted access.
    'weight' => 1,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Also as Attiks points out you've forgotten to return `$items` from the menu hook.

Finally, simply refreshing the page won't work when you add a menu item (they are cached), so you need to clear Drupal's caches to see the new item.

Answer (score 2):

You forget the return $items line.

Also rename create_report to kameleon_create_report_create_report to avoid namespace clashes.